# Is it possible to read and write cookies using BHO in internet explorer

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, cookies, browser

I am working  an extension for Internet explorer to read network traffic using BHO in C++. My code is based on the following,

https://github.com/salsita/passthruapp

Is there a way that I can access cookies that are stored on the browser? I want to be able to read a cookie set for a particular domain and also store a cookie for the domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [InternetGetCookieEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384714%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [InternetSetCookieEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385108%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  My goal was just to expire cookies so I had the following:

```
#define EXPIRED_COOKIE_DATE   L"expires = Sat,01-Jan-2000 00:00:00 GMT"
void ExpireCookies( const CString& strUrl )
{
   DWORD dwSize;
   BOOL bResult = InternetGetCookieEx( strUrl, NULL, NULL, &dwSize, INTERNET_COOKIE_HTTPONLY, NULL );

   if ( !bResult || dwSize <= 0 )
      return;

   TCHAR *lpszData = new TCHAR[dwSize];
   LPCWSTR usrauth = NULL;

   bResult = InternetGetCookieEx( strUrl, usrauth, lpszData, &dwSize, INTERNET_COOKIE_HTTPONLY, NULL );
   if ( !bResult )
      goto Exit;

   {
      CString cookieDataString( lpszData );

      int nTokenPos = 0;
      CString cookie = cookieDataString.Tokenize( _T( "; " ), nTokenPos );

      while ( nTokenPos >= 0 )
      {
         int separator = cookie.Find( _T( '=' ) );
         CString cookieName = cookie.Left( separator );
         CString value = cookie.Mid( separator + 1 );

         VERIFY( InternetSetCookieEx( strUrl, cookieName, EXPIRED_COOKIE_DATE, INTERNET_COOKIE_HTTPONLY, NULL ) );

         cookie = cookieDataString.Tokenize( _T( "; " ), nTokenPos );
      }
   }

Exit:
   SAFE_DELETE_ARR( lpszData );
}
```

Hope it helps you some!